# Dynamic Programming - Coins

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider the following piece of pseudo code, where `d` is the array of denomination values, `k` is the number of denominations, and `n` is the amount for which change is to be made.

```
Change(d; k; n)
1 C[0]  <- 0
2 for p <-  1 to n
3     min  <- INFINITE
4     for i  <- 1 to k
5         if d[i] <= p then
6           if 1 + C[p - d[i]] < min then
7               min  <- 1 + C[p - d[i]]
8               coin  <- i
9     C[p] <-  min
10    S[p] <-  coin
11 return C and S
```

I have read a lot of info about this specific problem, but still I don't understand why :
`1 + C[p-d[i]]` --> I really don't get this part, why do you use it, can someone please explain this to me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to answer your question, you need to understand what each variable represents, and what the algorithm is doing high level.

The process by which the algorithm arrives at the solution tries to count the number of coins that is needed to make change for all amounts from `1` through `n`, inclusive. That is the purpose of the outer loop: it iterates the current "goal" from `1` through `n`, letting the loop body come up with the answer for that goal.

Essentially, the algorithm goes like this:

- I know that if the amount is zero, I need zero coins to make change
- See how many coins I need to make change for `1`
- Knowing how many coins I need to make change for `1`, see how many coins I need to make change for `2`
- Knowing how many coins I need to make change for `1` through `2`, see how many coins I need to make change for `3`
- Knowing how many coins I need to make change for `1` through `4`, see how many coins I need to make change for `4`
- ...
- Knowing how many coins I need to make change for `1` through `n-1`, see how many coins I need to make change for `n`

The value of `p` represents the current goal - i.e. the amount for which we are trying to make change. The array `C` represents the solutions that we have found so far for all amounts from `1` to `p-1`, inclusive.

For each amount the algorithm tries using coins in each denomination `d[i]` to find a solution.

Now you are ready to understand the meaning of `1 + C[p-d[i]]`: we are trying to make change for `p`, so `C[p-d[i]]` is the smallest number of coins needed to come up with the change for `p-d[i]`. Therefore, the formula says that "if I know that it takes `x` coins to make change for `p-d[i]`, and I have a coin in denomination of `d[i]`, then I can reach `p` by adding one `d[i]` coin (hence, the `1 + ...` portion of the expression).

Comment: @FraK By the time you get to `p=4` your `C[]` will look like this: `{0:0, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2}`. This means that `1` and `2` can be made with a single coin, and that you need 2 coins to make `3`. So now the inner loop will try to set `C[4]` to some value. It will try `d[0]`, check `C[4-d[0]]` (i.e. `C[3]`, which equals to 2), and say that it needs one extra coin of denomination `1` to make `4` from `3`. It will set `C[4]=3`, and move on to the next coin. The next coin is `2`, so the algorithm will see that `1+C[4-2]` is less than `C[4]`, and set `C[4]` to `2`.

Comment: Thanks for the whole explanation, and I get it except for the last part, let's say we have d = {1,2,5} and I have my p = 4, then in the inner loop : (d[0]=1)<=4 then if (1 + c[4-1])<= INFINITE , this would yeld : 1+2 <= INFINITE finally min = 3, I really don't see the logic here, please explain it to me, I mean I know it work's but I dunno why ? more specific, why sustract the position of d[i] !!!

Comment: Nevermind I just figure it out ! What you said is just right, although I might have been looking at it in other way, in other terms:

Comment: If I choose d[i](a denomination) to be part of the solution, that means, that I will use ONE coin of the d[i] denomination, which can be {1,2,5}. But I still need to sum the number of coins I need to reach my p goal, until now I have only choose one coin of value d[i], now I need to add the coins I need to complete my goal p, which would be p-d[i], that is, my goal minus the AMOUNT of the coin d[i] I chose to use. It was as simple as that, my confusion was with the number of coins and the actual value of the coin in d[i].THANK YOU very much for your help ! Hope this can help others.